# Can we have more than one key value for method in RequestLogger for testcafe

Tags: testing, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
const logger = RequestLogger({url : /.*/, method : 'PUT'},{
  logResponseHeaders: true,
  logResponseBody:    true,
  logRequestHeaders:  true,
  logRequestBody:     true,
  stringifyRequestBody: true,
  stringifyResponseBody: true
});
```

The above code is fine. But what if we have more than one method value like `PUT`,`POST`,`PATCH` etc?

I tried something like

```
const logger = RequestLogger({url : /.*/, method : {'PUT','POST'}}
```

but it seems we cannot use. Do we have any other options

Answer (score 2):

You can use a predicate to filter requests by several values of the `method` property:

```js
const logger = RequestLogger(request => {
    return request.url === 'http://example.com' &&
           (request.method === 'post' || request.method === 'put')
});
```

Please refer to the following example in the TestCafe documentation: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook.html#filter-with-a-predicate